# Why can't I evaluate a composition of implemented_functions in SymPy at a point?

Tags: python, sympy

The code is pretty self-explanatory:

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function
>>> f = implemented_function('f', lambda x: x ** 2)
>>> g = implemented_function('g', lambda x: 2 * x)
>>> print(f(  2 ).evalf())
4.00000000000000
>>> print(  g(2) .evalf())
4.00000000000000
>>> print(f(g(2)).evalf())
f(g(2))
```

This is driving me nuts. Why is the expression not being evaluated, and how am I supposed to fix it?

Comment: You could use `lambdify`: `x = sympy.symbols('x')`; `sympy.lambdify(x, f(g(x)))(2)` evaluates to 16.

Comment: @unutbu: Doesn't that defeat the point of using `implemented_function`? If I could rely on having a generic symbolic expression then I would just manipulate it normally and do a substitution instead of going through `implemented_function`.

Comment: Did you tried `f(g(2).evalf()).evalf()` or `f(g(2).evalf())` ? maybe it's not what you were looking for.

Comment: @pazitos10: No, it is not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider this to be a bug in SymPy. `evalf` isn't calling `_imp_` recursively. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12092).

Regarding `_imp_` vs. `eval`, the docstring of `implemented_function` [says](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.implemented_function):

> Be aware that this is a quick workaround, not a general method to create special symbolic functions. If you want to create a symbolic function to be used by all the machinery of SymPy you should subclass the Function class.

The main purpose of `_imp_` is to be used in lambdify, to attach a numerical implementation to a symbolic function.

If you are only interested in symbolic evaluation, or evaluation with `evalf`, you should subclass `Function` and define `eval` or `_eval_evalf` (respectively).

Comment: +1 Ahh, I didn't realize it was explicitly meant for numerical evaluation! That explains some things. Okay so kind of a tangent, but if I do it this way then I will still have to override `fdiff` to make it differentiable, right? Or will it automatically differentiate the symbolic expression I return? (though I guess I could just do it and see)

Comment: If you return an expression from `eval`, that will make it evaluate immediately. So diff will evaluate on the expression that is returned. If you make it stay unevaluated (return `None` from `eval`), you will need to define the derivative.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks!! That actually makes my life easier in the cases where I do have an expression to return. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question directly, and I don't know what your overall goal is. But is this approach of any use?

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> class square(Function):
...     @classmethod
...     def eval(cls, x):
...         if x.is_integer or x.is_real:
...             return x**2
... 
>>> class double(Function):
...     @classmethod
...     def eval(cls, x):
...         if not x.is_integer or x.is_real:
...             return 2*x
... 
>>> double(square(3))
18
>>> var('x')
x
>>> double(square(x)).subs(x,5)
50
```

Comment: I have no idea what the implications of this method are (I didn't know `eval` even exists). How is this different from using `_imp_` or `implemented_function`? Is this normal or is it a hack?

Comment: Definitely not a hack. AS Meurer mentioned it in one his answers a few days ago. I have no idea how it might differ from the codes you mention. I imagine this is the arrangement for adding arbitrary functions to sympy.

Comment: +1 Interesting, thanks. Makes me wonder what the point of `_imp_` was if this works so well... there's gotta be something we're giving up!

Comment: Such a pessimist. ;)

Comment: Fun, I just found another bug in SymPy. Try changing `@classmethod` to `@staticmethod` and removing the first parameter, and it will infer `nargs` incorrectly...

Comment: I take this passage from that doc to be a warning about this code: "In order for my_func to become useful, several other methods would need to be implemented. See source code of some of the already implemented functions for more complete examples.

Also, if the function can take more than one argument, then nargs must be defined ..."